# How do I clear a label using Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm using labels to display who wins in a game of Tic Tac Toe I made. However, when the label gets overwritten with different text, the old text under it doesn't get cleared, only overwritten. So, some of the old text sometimes pokes through. Is there a way to clear a label to accomplish this without just making different labels that go in the same spot? If I try to use the `.destroy()` method on a label I get a bad window path error.

Here is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk


class TicTacToe(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # Vars
        self.players = Players()
        self.rounds_played = 0
        self.turn = 0
        self.hz = [0,3,6]
        self.clicked_buttons = []

        # Attributes
        self.resizable(False, False)

        # Start
        self.game_title = tk.Label(text="Stew's Tic Tac Toe")
        self.name_label = tk.Label(text="Make a name\n(Press the \'Enter\' key to submit)")
        self.name_entry = tk.Entry()
        self.symbol_label = tk.Label(text="Pick your symbol")
        self.symbol_buttons = [tk.Button(text="[X]", command=lambda: self.symbol_select(0)),
                               tk.Button(text="[O]", command=lambda: self.symbol_select(1))]
        self.next = tk.Button(text="Next", command=self.next_button)
        self.start_game = tk.Button(text="Start", command=self.start)
        self.game_title.grid(row=0)
        self.name_label.grid(row=1)
        self.name_entry.grid(row=2)
        self.name_entry.bind("<Return>", lambda x: self.set_player_name(self.players.player))

    def set_player_name(self, num):
        if num == 0:
            self.players.name = [self.name_entry.get().strip(" ")]
            if len(self.players.name[0].strip(" ")) == 0:
                self.players.name = ["Player 1"]
            if self.players.name[0] == "":
                self.players.name = ["Player 1"]
            if self.players.name[0] ==  " ":
                self.players.name = ["Player 1"]
            self.symbol_label.grid(row=3,)
            self.symbol_buttons[0].grid(row=4, sticky=tk.W, padx=57.5)
            self.symbol_buttons[1].grid(row=4, sticky=tk.E, padx=57.5)
        elif num == 1:
            self.players.name.append(self.name_entry.get().strip(" "))
            if len(self.players.name) >= 3:
                self.players.name[1] = self.players.name[2]
                self.players.name.pop(2)

            if len(self.players.name[0].strip(" ")) == 0:
                self.players.name = ["Player 1"]
            if self.players.name[1] == "":
                self.players.name.pop(1)
                self.players.name.append("Player 2")
            if self.players.name[1] == " ":
                self.players.name.pop(1)
                self.players.name.append("Player 2")
            if self.players.name[1] == self.players.name[0]:
                self.players.name[0] = f"{self.players.name[0]}1"
                self.players.name[1] = f"{self.players.name[1]}2"
            self.start_game.grid(row=4)

    def symbol_select(self, num):
        if num == 0:
            self.players.symbol = ["[X]",
                           "[O]"]
        else:
            self.players.symbol = ["[O]",
                           "[X]"]
        self.next.grid(row=5)

    def next_button(self):
        self.players.player = 1
        self.next.grid_forget()
        self.name_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
        self.symbol_label.grid_forget()
        for x in self.symbol_buttons:
            x.grid_forget()

    def start(self):
        self.game_title.grid_forget()
        self.whos_turn = tk.Label(text=f"{self.players.name[0]}\'s Turn")
        self.whos_turn.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=3)
        self.start_game.grid_forget()
        self.name_label.grid_forget()
        self.name_entry.grid_forget()
        self.game_buttons = [tk.Button(text="[ ]", command=lambda: self.move_update(0)),
                             tk.Button(text="[ ]", command=lambda: self.move_update(1)),
                             tk.Button(text="[ ]", command=lambda: self.move_update(2)),
                             tk.Button(text="[ ]", command=lambda: self.move_update(3)),
                             tk.Button(text="[ ]", command=lambda: self.move_update(4)),
                             tk.Button(text="[ ]", command=lambda: self.move_update(5)),
                             tk.Button(text="[ ]", command=lambda: self.move_update(6)),
                             tk.Button(text="[ ]", command=lambda: self.move_update(7)),
                             tk.Button(text="[ ]", command=lambda: self.move_update(8))]
        num = 0
        for r in range(0,3):
            for c in range(0,3):
                self.game_buttons[num].grid(row=(r%3 + 1), column=(c%3 + 1))
                num = num + 1
        self.rounds = tk.Label(text=f"Rounds Played: {self.rounds_played}")
        self.stats_title = tk.Label(text="Player\'s Stats")
        self.player_stats = [tk.Label(text=f"{self.players.name[0]}\'s Wins: {self.players.wins[0]}"),
                             tk.Label(text=f"{self.players.name[1]}\'s Wins: {self.players.wins[1]}")]
        self.rounds.grid(row=5, column=1, columnspan=3)
        self.stats_title.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.player_stats[0].grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.player_stats[1].grid(row=2, column=0)

    def move_update(self, num):
        if num not in self.clicked_buttons:
            self.clicked_buttons.append(num)
            self.players.turn = self.players.turn + 1
            if self.players.turn%2 == 1:
                self.game_buttons[num].config(text=self.players.symbol[0], relief=tk.SUNKEN)
                self.whos_turn.config(text=f"{self.players.name[1]}\'s Turn")
            elif self.players.turn%2 == 0:
                self.game_buttons[num].config(text=self.players.symbol[1], relief=tk.SUNKEN)
                self.whos_turn.config(text=f"{self.players.name[0]}\'s Turn")
        if self.players.turn != 9:
            self.check_for_winner()
        if self.players.turn == 9:
            if self.check_for_winner() != 1:
                self.round_end(0)

    def check_for_winner(self):
        # Check Which Symbol Won
        for n in range(0, 2):
            # Check if Winner (Vertical)
            for x in range(0, 3):
                if self.game_buttons[x]["text"] == self.players.symbol[n] and self.game_buttons[x + 3]["text"] == self.players.symbol[
                    n]:
                    if self.game_buttons[x + 6]["text"] == self.players.symbol[n]:
                        self.round_end(n + 1)
                        return 1
            # Check if Winner (Horizontal)
            for x in range(0, 9):
                if x in self.hz and self.game_buttons[x]["text"] == self.players.symbol[n]:
                    if self.game_buttons[x + 1]["text"] == self.players.symbol[n] and self.game_buttons[x + 2]["text"] == self.players.symbol[n]:
                        self.round_end(n + 1)
                        return 1
            # Check if Winner (Left Diagonal)
            if self.game_buttons[0]["text"] == self.players.symbol[n] and self.game_buttons[4]["text"] == self.players.symbol[n]:
                if self.game_buttons[8]["text"] == self.players.symbol[n]:
                    self.round_end(n + 1)
                    return 1
            # Check if Winner (Right Diagonal)
            if self.game_buttons[2]["text"] == self.players.symbol[n] and self.game_buttons[4]["text"] == self.players.symbol[n]:
                if self.game_buttons[6]["text"] == self.players.symbol[n]:
                    self.round_end(n + 1)
                    return 1

    def round_end(self ,num):
        for x in self.game_buttons:
            x.config(relief=tk.SUNKEN, state=tk.DISABLED)
        self.rounds_played = self.rounds_played + 1
        self.rounds.configure(text=f"Rounds Played: {self.rounds_played}")
        self.round_winner = tk.Label()
        self.play_again = tk.Button(text="Play Again?", command=self.new_game)
        self.play_again.grid(row=6, column=1, columnspan=3)
        if num == 0:
            self.round_winner.grid(row=4, column=1, columnspan=3)
            self.round_winner.destroy()
            self.round_winner.grid(row=4, column=1, columnspan=3)
            self.round_winner.config(text="It was a Tie!")
        elif num == 1:
            self.round_winner.grid(row=4, column=1, columnspan=3)
            self.round_winner.config(text=f"{self.players.name[0]} Wins!")
            self.players.wins = [self.players.wins[0] + 1, self.players.wins[1]]
            self.player_stats[0].config(text=f"{self.players.name[0]}\'s Wins: {self.players.wins[0]}")
        elif num == 2:
            self.round_winner.grid(row=4, column=1, columnspan=3)
            self.round_winner.destroy()
            self.round_winner.grid(row=4, column=1, columnspan=3)
            self.round_winner.config(text=f"{self.players.name[1]} Wins!")
            self.players.wins = [self.players.wins[0], self.players.wins[1] + 1]
            self.player_stats[1].config(text=f"{self.players.name[1]}\'s Wins: {self.players.wins[1]}")

    def new_game(self):
        self.players.turn = 0
        for x in self.game_buttons:
            x.config(state=tk.ACTIVE, text="[ ]", relief=tk.RAISED)
        self.clicked_buttons = []


class Players:
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.name = []
        self.symbol = []
        self.wins = [0, 0]
        self.player = 0
        self.turn = 0



game = TicTacToe()
game.mainloop()
```

The relevant part is this (Lines 161-164 of 196)

```
self.round_winner.grid(row=4, column=1, columnspan=3)
self.round_winner.destroy()
self.round_winner.grid(row=4, column=1, columnspan=3)
self.round_winner.config(text="It was a Tie!")
```

Answer (score 1):

You only need to update the text in the labels; it is not necessary to re-create and re-grid the labels for each game.
The score needs to be updated as well.
`self.update()` may be overkill; you can probably replace it with `self.update_idletasks()`, or delete it entirely.

```
def round_end(self ,num):
    for x in self.game_buttons:
        x.config(relief=tk.SUNKEN, state=tk.DISABLED)
    self.rounds_played = self.rounds_played + 1
    self.rounds.configure(text=f"Rounds Played: {self.rounds_played}")
    self.round_winner = tk.Label()
    self.play_again = tk.Button(text="Play Again?", command=self.new_game)
    self.play_again.grid(row=6, column=1, columnspan=3)

    if num == 0:
        self.round_winner.config(text="It was a Tie!")
        self.update()

    elif num == 1:
        self.players.wins[0] += 1
        self.player_stats[0].config(text=f"{self.players.name[0]}\'s Wins: {self.players.wins[0]}")
        self.update()

    elif num == 2:
        self.round_winner.config(text=f"{self.players.name[1]} Wins!")
        self.players.wins[1] += 1
        self.player_stats[1].config(text=f"{self.players.name[1]}\'s Wins: {self.players.wins[1]}")
        self.update()
```

Comment: The config updates the text, but it overwrites the old label. Does the update function clear the old one?

Comment: I guess I'm just really confused on what that does. The increment by one was helpful, so thanks for that. However,the self.update() didn't help. I don't really understand what it is trying to do either. Could you please explain it more?